# How do I copy an android app to an actual device?

Tags: android

I have written a simple android app and it runs in the emulator.
Now how do I actually copy it to my phone? I have HTC's Eris. When I attach it with USB it asks me If I want to mount it as a USB mass storage device. I then see it in my drive list.

the directories on the device are:

```
albumthumbs
amazonmp3
com.google.android.apps.listen
ComicReader
data
DCIM
download
media
music
rosie_scroll
```

Now what should I copy from my Project directory and where should I put it?
And is there any other process I need to run to "install" my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `adb` tool provides a command for installing an application onto the phone, `adb install ...`.  It takes the `.apk` file as an arguement.  `adb --help` has a bit more info.

Comment: It says I have insufficient permissions on the device. Even if I use sudo.

Comment: You have to tell you phone to allow non-market applications. On my G1 this is done through Settings->Applications->Unknown sources.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Eclipse, you can setup Eclipse to publish the application to a connected device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply copy the .apk file to the sdcard and navigate to it using a file manager such as Astro. Long press on it, and Astro will install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use HTC Sync, if you are on Windows..

At least for Hero, it will automatically install APK files on my phone, when I double click them

Download: http://www.htc.com/us/support/droid-eris-verizon/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Install ADB driver. Have your phone in USB debugging mode. In an opened eclipse code press ctrl+F11. it will show your device. Run through it